# Using caret sign (^) in package.json doesn't upgrade minor version

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

In my package.json file I have the line:

```
"typescript": "^4.1.6",
```

The caret sign(^) says that if there is a minor typescript version higher than 4.1, npm will install this version.

However, when I run "npm list", I see that the installed Typescript version is exactly 4.1.6.
I can see here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html
that there are handful of minor Typescript versions above version 4.1, so why am I still getting 4.1.6?

Comment: Do you have a lockfile forcing this version?

Answer (score 1):

With `npm outdated` you can see a list of available updates.

You can also use an online tool https://pkgui.com/npm

`npm list` only lists all the packages installed locally.

Answer (score 0):

Package managers read node_modules, skipping packages that are already installed.
Package managers have lock files, preventing changing the installing version.
Just `npm install` won't work

Run `npm up` (=`npm upgrade`) or `npm up typescript` to update (all the pachages) the package to its latest available version

Answer (score -1):

Once I:

1. deleted the package.json file
2. deleted the entire node_modules folder
3. ran "npm install" again

I saw that Typescript version 4.9.5 was installed